# Add region-labels below x-axis

Tags: plotting, labeling

I need to add arrows & text that determine which function has the highest value in a given region. I do not even know where to start. Imagine I have the following plot:

```
  line1 = Line[{{.292893, 0}, {.292893, 2}}];
  line2 = Line[{{.75, 0}, {.75, 2}}];
  Plot[
  {.5 x^2 + 1, x + .75, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1},
   Epilog -> {line1, line2}
   ]
```

[image]

And this is what I need: 
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line1 = Line[{{.292893, 0}, {.292893, 2}}];
line2 = Line[{{.75, 0}, {.75, 2}}];
arrow = {
   Arrowheads[{-.1, .1}],
   Arrow[{{0, -0.1}, {.292893, -0.1}}],
   Arrow[{{.292893, -0.1}, {.75, -0.1}}],
   Arrow[{{.75, -0.1}, {1, -0.1}}]
   };
text = {Text["region A", {.292893/2, -0.4}],
   Text["region B", {.53, -0.4}],
   Text["region C", {.89, -0.4}]
   };
Plot[{.5 x^2 + 1, x + .75, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 2}} , 
 Epilog -> {line1, line2, arrow, text}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought about something that is separate and not in the plot. But of course, this is also a way to do it!

Comment: @KarlA, take a look at kglr’s use of labeled arrows, you might save yourself a lot of finagling to get the text positioning as you would like it. Very nice answer though, wuyudi!

Answer (score 3):

You can also add text labels using custom `Arrowheads`:

```
ClearAll[arrowHeads, labeledArrows]
arrowHeads[lbls_,  offset_: 2, size_: .04] := Arrowheads[{-size, 
   {Automatic, Automatic, Graphics @ Text[#, {0, 0}, {0, offset}]}, 
    size}] & /@ lbls;

labeledArrows[lbls_, lst_,  offset_: 2, size_: .04] := MapThread[
   List, {arrowHeads[lbls, offset, size], Arrow /@ Partition[lst, 2, 1]}];
```

***Examples:***

```
labels = {"region 1", "region 2", "region 3"};
list = Thread[{{0, .29, .75, 1}, -.25}];

Plot[{.5 x^2 + 1, x + .75, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.03]}},
 GridLines -> {{.292893, .75}, None}, 
 Epilog -> labeledArrows[labels, list]]
```

[image]

You can add styling directives and use the third and fourth arguments to control the label position and the size of the arrow glyph, respectively:

```
Plot[{.5 x^2 + 1, x + .75, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.03]}},
 GridLines -> {{.292893, .75}, None}, 
 Epilog -> {{labeledArrows[labels, list],
   Dashed, labeledArrows[{"region 4"}, {{.29, 2 .29 - .1}, {.75, 2 .75 - .1}}], 
   Dotted, Red, FontColor -> Purple, FontSize -> 12, 
    labeledArrows[{"label 1", "label 2", "label 3"},
      Thread[{{0, .29, .75, 1}, 2.1}], -1, .06]}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to use `labeledArrows` is to generate a graphics object and use `Grid` to show it under the main plot. (Note the use of special settings for `ImageSize`, `PlotRangePadding` and `ImagePadding` to align the two graphics objects):

```
options = {ImageSize -> 1 -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, Automatic}}};

plot = Plot[{.5 x^2 + 1, x + .75, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  GridLines -> {{.292893, .75}, None}, Evaluate @ options];

arrowsandlabels = Graphics[labeledArrows[labels, Thread[{{0, .29, .75, 1}, 0}]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.05, 0.01}}, Evaluate @ options];

Grid[{{plot}, {arrowsandlabels}}, Alignment -> Right, Spacings -> {None, 1}]
```

[image]